# How can I run NUnit test in VS Code with .NET TEST EXPLORER

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, nunit

I would like to run unit tests from [.NET TEST EXPLORER](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer), not the command line. I *can* run tests when navigating to the unit test directory and executing `dotnet test`.

But selecting **.NET TEST EXPLORER** shows:

> Please open or set the test project and ensure your project compiles

Is it related to the `NUnit` nature of the test project?
Project *does* compile. How do I set the test project?

Comment: Your answer might be depend on your project situation, But we really don't need to set anything. If its test project, VS defaultly showing Test Explorer. Also, Your error seems like project configuation dependency.

Comment: It is likely that you'll need to provide more details. For example: What is the target framework for the assembly containing the tests? What is the output of `dotnet --info`? What version of VS Code are you using? What version of .NET Test Explorer? All of these can potentially help diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 5):

In **VISUAL STUDIO CODE**, select the Settings wheel (Manage) > Extensions > Workspace Settings > Test Project Path

Enter the *relative* path to the unit test project: `MyProject.Test/MyProject.Test.csprojx`.

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't show the tests. I'm using 4.6.2. Does it only work with Core tests?

Comment: Worked for me, but I found it at under Settings > Extensions > .NET Core Test Explorer > Test Project Path

Answer (score 2):

Select the Settings wheel (Manage)
-> Extensions
-> Workspace Settings
-> Test Project Path

Enter:

```
*Tests*
```

if you have "Tests" in your project's name.

Source: [Interactive Unit Testing with .NET Core and VS Code By John V. Petersen](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2009101/Interactive-Unit-Testing-with-.NET-Core-and-VS-Code)

Comment: That link has a great tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path by adding this line in the `settings.json`:

```
"dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath": "Tests"
```